# Sony Audio API questions

Tags: sony-audio-control-api

According to Sony's website, they've discontinued support for the Sony Audio Api that underlies their Music Center app and scrubbed all information to it with no archive.

I have a Sony GTK-XB72 that has audio reactive front lights that can be controlled from the Music Center app. I've search the internet and cannot find an example of using the API to control or disable the lights as can be done in the app.

Has anyone done this? Perhaps it is an undocumented feature?

I've only tried to find information about the Sony Audio Api, as it is no longer supported by Sony nor is their page archived on their website.